# ¿Por qué es necesario hacer un alias en la tabla que queremos utilizar en una consulta interna?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mientras intentaba averiguar qué son la *root*, los elementos intermedios y las *leaf* de un árbol representado en una base de datos Mysql y descubrí una cosa muy extraña con las asimilaciones de bases de datos con `AS`. Efectivamente, si no pongo un alias con la tabla sobre la que estoy haciendo pruebas IF/ELSE no puedo utilizarla en esas pruebas IF/ELSE.
Por ejemplo con esta tabla :

```
N  P
-- --
1  2
3  2
5  6
7  6
2  4
6  4
4  15
8  9
10 9
12 13
14 13
9  11
13 11
11 15
15 NULL
```

Por primero intento utilizar la table en los tests sin hacer un alias en `FROM BST WHERE P = BST.N` y no funciona:

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL,'Root', 
             IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P = N)>0,'Inner', 'Leaf'))
             FROM BST ORDER BY N
```

Pero en el segundo, con el alias funciona:

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL, 'Root', 
             IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner', 'Leaf')) 
             FROM BST AS B ORDER BY N
```

Me devuelve los resultados:

```
N  X
-- -------
1  Leaf 
2  Inner 
3  Leaf 
4  Inner 
5  Leaf 
6  Inner 
7  Leaf 
8  Leaf 
9  Inner 
10 Leaf 
11 Inner 
12 Leaf 
13 Inner 
14 Leaf 
15 Root
```

¿Por qué es necesario hacer un alias sobre la tabla que queremos utilizar en IF/ELSE?

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado y qué no has entendido de eso que has investigado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad no siempre es necesario poner un alias a la tabla. En tu caso, si que es necesario porque

- la tabla de la sub-consulta es la misma de la consulta principal y
- tu quieres comparar el valor de la fila de la sub-consulta con el valor de la fila de la consulta principal para esta misma tabla.

Veamos primero como funciona el mecanismo de resolución de nombres de columnas cuando no están calificadas (`Columna` versus `Tabla.Columna` o `alias.Columna`).:

Cuando el motor encuentra un nombre de columna sin calificar, sigue un proceso bien definido para encontrar a qué tabla pertenece la columna que se quiere comparar.

Para ello, ve dentro de las columnas de las tablas referenciadas en la cláusula `from`. Si encuentra una tabla que tiene una columna con el mismo nombre, internamente asocia la columna a dicha tabla. Si encuentra que varias tablas tienen una columna con el nombre buscado, al no poder determinar sin ambigüedad a que tabla asociar el nombre, genera un error del tipo:

> Column 'columna' in field list is ambiguous

Solo después, si la consulta que hace referencia a la columna es una sub-consulta de otra, cambia al ámbito de la consulta principal para realizar el mismo proceso.

Dado que tu estás referenciando la misma tabla en la consulta principal y en la sub-consulta, cuando haces esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P = N
```

Dado que tanto la columna `P` como la columna `N` existen en la tabla `BST`, el motor interpreta que quieres comparar el valor de `P` con el valor de `N` para cada fila de `BST` (sin *ver* los valores de la fila de la consulta principal).

Si las tablas fuesen distintas, podías escribir la consulta sin poner alias a las tablas, supongamos que tenemos dos tablas que tienen las mismas columnas `Columna1` a `Columna3`, y esta consulta:

```
SELECT Columna1
       (select Columna3 from Tabla2 where Tabla2.Columna2 = Tabla1.Columna3)
  from Tabla1
```

Aunque `Columna2` y `Columna3` existan en ambas tablas, el motor sabe exactamente de qué tabla tomar el valor de cada columna para hacer la comparación.

En tu consulta, dado que la tabla de ambas consultas es la misma, esta técnica tampoco es suficiente, por lo cual es necesario poner alias por lo menos una vez a alguna de las tablas para romper la ambigüedad. También podría ponerse alias a ambas tablas, así sería aún más claro:

```
ELECT N
      , IF(  P IS NULL
           , 'Root'
           , IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST Secundaria WHERE Secundaria.P = Principal.N) > 0, 'Inner', 'Leaf')) 
 FROM BST Principal ORDER BY N
```